# Automatically go through pages download filtered links on a site

Tags: firefox, automation, firefox-extensions, download-manager, screen-scraping

With DownThemAll! I can download all the links on a given page and I can filter them.

lets say the site is www.google.com
and I want to grab all the search results. I set up a filter: /search?q=

This will grab all the search results on that page (and a few junk links - but thats not relevant here). But I want all the search results. Not just from this page but from all the google pages lsited at the bottom. Can I instruct DownThemAll! to go through each page and automatically download according to that filter?

If not with DownThemAll!, then how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an awesome program called imacros works with Firefox, Chrome, IE or on it's own. Easily automates browser tasks and can be enhanced with javascript.